# Which Pandas method to use over rows given condition?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Have partly solved the data-task using for loops and lists in python but reviewer was not satisfied.
Could you help with taking advantage of pandas methods. Can not find much in the documentation and forums. Basically, if for each store period_id[q]-period_id[q-1]!=1 then the number of periods increases by 1.
My take on the task:

```
for i in range(len(period_id)-1):
    if (period_id[i+1] - period_id[i])!=1:
        promo_count=0
        total_period_count+=1
        Number_of_promo_periods.append(total_period_count)
        Duration.append(promo_count)
    else:
        promo_count+=1
        Number_of_promo_periods.append('')
        Duration.append(promo_count)

data['Number_of_promo_periods']=Number_of_promo_periods
data['Duration']=Duration
    store_id    period_id   sales_volume    Number_of_promo_periods     Duration    period_total_sale
724224  4168621     191     2.25    1   0   
216520  4168621     192     6.35        1   
175105  4168621     193     7.05        2   
699084  4168621     194     2.50        3   
780957  4168621     195     1.70        4   
403579  4168621     196     4.75        5   
385893  4168621     197     4.90        6   
415417  4168621     198     4.70        7   
106273  4168621     199     10.00       8   
493167  4168621     200     4.10        9   
683860  4168621     201     2.60        10  
73777   4168621     202     14.80       11  
599425  4168621     203     3.30        12  
137835  4168621     204     8.15        13  
296985  4168621     205     5.50        14  
548164  4168621     206     3.70        15  86.35
296984  4168621     208     5.50    2   0   
453535  4168621     209     4.40        1   9.9
336839  4168621     211     5.25    3   0   
630290  4168621     212     3.05        1   
385922  4168621     213     4.90        2   
679706  4168621     214     2.65        3   15.85
```

Given

```
        store_id  period_id  sales_volume
724224   4168621        191          2.25
216520   4168621        192          6.35
175105   4168621        193          7.05
699084   4168621        194          2.50
780957   4168621        195          1.70
403579   4168621        196          4.75
385893   4168621        197          4.90
415417   4168621        198          4.70
106273   4168621        199         10.00
493167   4168621        200          4.10
683860   4168621        201          2.60
73777    4168621        202         14.80
599425   4168621        203          3.30
137835   4168621        204          8.15
296985   4168621        205          5.50
548164   4168621        206          3.70
296984   4168621        208          5.50
453535   4168621        209          4.40
336839   4168621        211          5.25
630290   4168621        212          3.05
385922   4168621        213          4.90
679706   4168621        214          2.65
```

Comment: Why is `period_id` `216` to `218` missing in your expected output?

Comment: It is missing by design, period_id contains only values when there is a promo_period in a store. Basically, when there is a missing variable it means end of the promo_period and start of the new promo_period

Comment: There are much more rows in the data with different product_ids and the missing values indicate the beginning/end of the promo_period

Comment: The full last 'period' (216, 217, 218) is missing not values between periods and they are only missing in your expected output.

Comment: True, edited out to eliminate confusion. But in the final picture - yes, it would count as a new promo_period. 4th one. In the end there are around 100’000 of such.

Comment: You can use shift(1) from pandas and create new column in dataframe as prev_peroidid then use a udf proably a lambda do cal the difference. Then add a running sum on the difference column.

Comment: I am severely limited to a number of lines I can use for the code. Tried shift() and diff() - failed miserably.

Comment: Michael solutions is exactly what I proposed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With pandas you can find the periods with [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) and use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to aggregate by `period`

```
df['nr_promo'] = df.period_id.diff().ne(1).cumsum()
gr = df.groupby('nr_promo')
df['duration'] = gr.cumcount()
df['sale_total'] = gr['sales_volume'].transform('sum')

df
```

Out:

```
        store_id  period_id  sales_volume  nr_promo  duration  sale_total
724224   4168621        191          2.25         1         0       86.35
216520   4168621        192          6.35         1         1       86.35
175105   4168621        193          7.05         1         2       86.35
699084   4168621        194          2.50         1         3       86.35
780957   4168621        195          1.70         1         4       86.35
403579   4168621        196          4.75         1         5       86.35
385893   4168621        197          4.90         1         6       86.35
415417   4168621        198          4.70         1         7       86.35
106273   4168621        199         10.00         1         8       86.35
493167   4168621        200          4.10         1         9       86.35
683860   4168621        201          2.60         1        10       86.35
73777    4168621        202         14.80         1        11       86.35
599425   4168621        203          3.30         1        12       86.35
137835   4168621        204          8.15         1        13       86.35
296985   4168621        205          5.50         1        14       86.35
548164   4168621        206          3.70         1        15       86.35
296984   4168621        208          5.50         2         0        9.90
453535   4168621        209          4.40         2         1        9.90
336839   4168621        211          5.25         3         0       15.85
630290   4168621        212          3.05         3         1       15.85
385922   4168621        213          4.90         3         2       15.85
679706   4168621        214          2.65         3         3       15.85
```

Comment: awesome, thank you. Did not expect it to be so elegantly solved.